# Do VueJS indexes update when newly added items are added?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component with a `v-for` loop displaying 3 Posts. I am making use of `index` in the loop so the posts have the following indexes

```
[0] Post 1
[1] Post 2
[2] Post 3
```

Within the `v-for` loop I am calling a function called `updatePost()` which takes 2 arguments the `post` and the `index`.  This makes an API call to update the post. Once the API call is finished I am using the `index` to modify the value of the post I intended to change.
As this is a real-time application with multiple users making posts if someone had added a new post just before I make an API call would VueJS know to update the index I had originally used in the function?

So, for example, I want to update the first post I would use the following:

```
updatePost(post, 0)
```

But before the API call is complete another user added a new Post shifting Post 1 index to 1. Would this cause the wrong post being updated?

```
[0] Newly added post
[1] Post 1
[2] Post 2
[3] Post 3
```

Comment: "Would this cause the wrong post being updated?" I don't think it would.  Once the api call is made, a snapshot of the array is used.  So a user adding another post would not be seen by the api until it runs again and gets a new snapshot of the array.

Comment: This is something that I am not 100% sure on. This is why I'm not sure if I can rely on using the index to make the update. Rather I would use something immutable like the Id but I would have to run a for-loop to find the post that matched to find the index of the post then carry out the update.

Comment: Without seeing how your API is being triggered, I'm not sure how the API would see the updated array if the array was updated after the API call had started.  You could set the array value to a local variable in your API call, and work from the local array in your API.  That would ensure that changes to the original array would not be seen by the API until the API call runs again.

Comment: You could also pass only the post you want to update to the API and not the whole array, thus not having to worry about the index from inside the API method.  something like ... updatePost(posts[0]).  This would make sure the updatePost() function is only getting the exact data it's supposed to update.

Comment: It's more to do with the client site. It will always update the right post on the server side. It's just on the client, I just want to make sure the right post is being updated, to reflect the server side change?

Comment: My gut tells me your concerned about a non-issue, but I can't say for sure without seeing some code.  Whatever data/array you pass to the API is all the API logic will know about.  So if a user updates the original posts array after the API call is made, the API won't know about the change to the original array until the API call fires again and you pass in the updated posts array.

Comment: `updatePost: function (post, index) {
        axios.post(‘/post’, {
            Id: post.id
        }).then(response => {
            post[index].description =response.data.description
        });
}`

So when there is a response the function is being called, my question is what happens if a new post has been added to the list of posts, will the index get updated too?

Comment: I know there will be no issue on the server side, its merely on the client side. Once an update has been completed on the server side you update the entity on the client side to reflect the change. This is the only thing I am concerned about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahhh ... i see now what you mean and how you're using the index after the API has been triggered.  I think you are correct in that if someone updates the original post array before the response is complete, the index will not be enough to accurately update the posts array with the response description.

```
// Your original code
updatePost: function(post, index) { 
  axios.post(‘/post’, { Id: post.id })
    .then(response => {
      post[index].description = response.data.description
  });
}
```

I would probably not worry about using the index at all as a method param and modify your logic to look something like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    posts: []
  }
},

methods: {
  updatePost: function(post) {
    axios.post('/post', { Id: post.id })
      .then(response => {
        let originalPost = this.posts.find(op => op.id == post.id);
        originalPost.description = response.data.description;
      });
  }
}
```

Then, when you initially call the updatePost method, you would just pass the specific array element index you want to update.  So something like this:

```
this.updatePost(this.posts[0])
```

This way, whenever the API response comes through, you are looking up the proper array element to update by matching the id in the post object, rather than using the index of the array.  Because, yes, if the posts[] array has changed before the response comes back, you can no longer rely on the array index to identify the correct post object to update.

Comment: I totally agree with you and this is what I am currently doing now, I am looking for the post array to find the post with the specific id to update it. I just wanted to find out whether VueJS automatically updated the index but I don't think it does.

Comment: I like the shorthand you used here `this.posts.find(op => op.id == post.id)` as opposed to using using a for loop

Comment: Vue does't really have any specific behavior when dealing with arrays.  It's just a javascript array.  If you have an array w/ three items, the indexes would be 0, 1, 2.  If you add an item to the end of the array, the previous items would still have the same indexes.  BUT, if you add to the beginning of the array, all the other items would have different indexes b/c the first item will always be index 0.

Comment: Check out this article on javascript array functions ... https://codeburst.io/useful-javascript-array-and-object-methods-6c7971d93230  It's amazing what you can do with filter(), find(), map(), every(), some() and reduce()!